# React app very slow in Chrome but significant smooth in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, react-redux

I have to build a react-redux site and i have some performance issues on chrome. I have a very big list of nested components rendered on my webpage. I have to build a modal menu that is opened in front of the already rendered list of components. In chrome is very very slow, even a click is taking very long. In firefox works pretty smooth.
I tried debugging with react dev tools and it's saying nothing is rendered in react but the app is very slow. I will attach some benchmarks with the fps. They are taken when the page is idle.

[This one is one chrome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDKa9.png)

And on Firefox the fps is steady on 60 fps. No drops.
What can be the issue on chrome.
I want to mention in background there are a lot of components but they are already rendered and do not suffer modifications.

Comment: This is exactly why we all use firefox.
The end of the chrome empire is coming.

Comment: I observed now when I check a checkbox it's taking like 1s to recalculate style

Comment: I can confirm the same with my website https://capmon.org/ . Especially on mobile its extremely slow with Chrome and edge but fast with Firefox

Comment: You can try to see if chrome is doing some recalculation on the entire dom. I think firefox is smarter figuring out if it has to recalculate everything or just some part of the dom.